# Ember jQuery UI sortable remove item not in sync

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js

component:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

_refreshSortable() {
    this.$().sortable('destroy');
    this.renderSortable();

},
fakeDataChanged: Ember.observer('fakeData.[]', function() {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this._refreshSortable);

}),

fakeData: [
    Ember.Object.create({id: 1, name: 'test'}),
    Ember.Object.create({id: 2, name: 'test1'}),
    Ember.Object.create({id: 3, name: 'test2'}),
    Ember.Object.create({id: 4, name: 'test3'}),
],

actions: {
    removeItem(item) {
        this.get('fakeData').removeObject(item);

    }

},
renderSortable() {
        this.$().sortable({
            opacity : 0.6,
            axis : 'y'

           });

           this.$().sortable().disableSelection();

   },

   _renderSortable: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function() {

       this.renderSortable();

   }),



});
```

template:

```
    {{#sortable-ui as |sortable|}}

        {{#each sortable.fakeData as |item|}}

            <li>{{item.name}}<button {{action "removeItem" item target=sortable}}>x</button></li>

        {{/each}}

    {{/sortable-ui}}
```

If you try and remove an item AFTER a sort is perform, it will either lock up the ability to remove, or remove items which it's not supposed to.

This is simplified code in order to describe the root problem.

Comment: I can just strongly recommend you to implement this in pure ember.

Comment: do you recommend using the html5 drag and drop api that ember supports? I need to support at least IE10, this is mainly the reason I have always used jQuery UI for complete browser support. I don't have much experience with D&D api.

Comment: yes, or better use an existing [addon](http://jgwhite.co.uk/ember-sortable/demo/).

Comment: solved the problem with jQuery ui, but I am now considering a move in the near future to one of the ember addons for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, a bit hacky, but one of the ways to solve this problem is:

```
  removed: true,

    didRender() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        this.set('removed', true);

    },



actions: {
    removeItem(item) {
        this.set('removed', false);
        this.get('fakeData').removeObject(item);
        this.rerender();

    }

},
```

then in template:

```
{{#sortable-ui as |sortable|}}
   {{#if sortable.removed}}
    {{#each sortable.fakeData as |item|}}

        <li>{{item.name}}<button {{action "removeItem" item target=sortable}}>x</button></li>

    {{/each}}

  {{/if}}

{{/sortable-ui}}
```